# Error en pintar Celda en Datatable php

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

Estoy realizando un crud, lo que quiero realizar es colorear la fila de color rojo. Si la fecha de ingreso ya tiene 5 o más días que se registro, Lo intente de varias formas pero no tuve exito, Soy aun nuevo en programación por lo cual se me dificultan algunas cosas, De igual forma coloco todo el codigo par que puedan entender lo que estoy realizando, tambien pedirles algun consejo de como poder mejorar mi codigo, puesto que he tenido ciertos detalles en la recuperacion de información, es decir cuando le doy click en editar me aroja el ultimo registro que seleccione y no el que quiero editar, no se si sea problema del navegador o de mis funciones.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  var id, opcion;
  opcion = 4;

  // Fecha actual en milisegundos
const today = Date.now();
function calcDays(dateStr) {
    // Separar fecha y hora
    let [dt, tm] = dateStr.split(' ');
    // Separar año, mes y día
    let [Y, M, D] = dt.split('-');
    // Separar horas, minutos y segundos
    let [h, m, s] = tm.split(':');
    
    // Crear objeto de fecha, se tienen que enviar todos los parámetros separados
    let dateObj = new Date(Y, M - 1, D, h, m, s);
    // Obtener diferencia entre ambas fechas, dividido entre 1000 para que sean segundos
    let timeDiff = parseInt((today - dateObj.getTime()) / 1000);
    // Dividir diferencia entre 86400 que son los segundos por día (60*60*24)
    let days = parseInt(timeDiff / 86400);
    // Fechas anteriores dan números positivos
    return days;
}

  tablaReportes = $("#tablaReportes").DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: "../controlador/reportes.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: { opcion: opcion },
      dataSrc: "",
    },
    //Para cambiar el lenguaje a español
    language: {
      lengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
      zeroRecords: "No se encontraron resultados",
      info: "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
      infoEmpty: "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
      infoFiltered: "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
      sSearch: "Buscar:",
      oPaginate: {
        sFirst: "Primero",
        sLast: "Último",
        sNext: "Siguiente",
        sPrevious: "Anterior",
      },
      sProcessing: "Procesando...",
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "id" },
      { data: "folio" },
      { data: "nombre" },
      { data: "apellido" },
      { data: "direccion" },
      { data: "descripcion_domicilio" },
      { data: "telefono" },
      { data: "num_contrato" },
      { data: "fecha_inicio" },
      { data: "fecha_final" },

      {
        data: "cuadrilla",
        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
          switch (data) {
            case "1":
              data =
                '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Operación ciudad</span>';
              break;
            case "2":
              data =
                '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Operación megasistema</span>';
              break;
            case "3":
              data =
                '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Drenajes</span>';
              break;
            case "4":
              data =
                '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Tomas tapadas</span>';
              break;
            case "5":
              data =
                '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">Cloración</span>';
              break;
            case "6":
              data = '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">Bacheo</span>';
              break;
            case "7":
              data =
                '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">Contratos</span>';
              break;
            case "8":
              data = '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">Otros</span>';
              break;
            default:
              data = "";
          }
          return data;
        },
      },
      {
        data: "estatus",
        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
          switch (data) {
            case "1":
              data = '<span class="badge badge-warning">Inicio</span>';
              break;
            case "2":
              data = '<span class="badge badge-warning">Pendiente</span>';
              break;
            case "3":
              data = '<span class="badge badge-success">Terminado</span>';
              break;
            case "4":
              data = '<span class="badge badge-danger">Cancelado</span>';
              break;
            default:
              data = "";
          }
          return data;
        },
      },
      { data: "observaciones" },
      { data: "encargado_cuadrilla" },
      { data: "otra_descripcion" },
      {
        defaultContent: `<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnPrint'><i class='material-icons'>print</i></button><button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons'>delete</i></button></div></div>`,
      },
    ],
    columnDefs: [
      {
        // Aplicar solo a celda 8
        targets: 8,
        // Ejecutar cuando se crea la celda
        createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        console.log(cellData, cellData[8], calcDays(cellData[8]));
          // Ejecuta la función para calcular diferencia
          if (calcDays(cellData[8]) >= 5) {
            $(td).css("background-color", "#E60026");
          }
        },
      },
    ],
    //para usar los botones
    responsive: "true",
    dom: "Bfrtilp",
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: "excelHtml5",
        text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
        titleAttr: "Exportar a Excel",
        className: "btn btn-success",
      },
      {
        extend: "pdfHtml5",
        text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
        titleAttr: "Exportar a PDF",
        className: "btn btn-danger",
      },
      {
        extend: "print",
        text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
        titleAttr: "Imprimir",
        className: "btn btn-info",
      },
    ],
  });
  var fila; //captura la fila, para editar o eliminar
  //submit para el Alta y Actualización
  $("#formReportes").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //evita el comportambiento normal del submit, es decir, recarga total de la página
    folio = $.trim($("#folio").val());
    nombre = $.trim($("#nombre").val());
    apellido = $.trim($("#apellido").val());
    direccion = $.trim($("#direccion").val());
    descripcion_domicilio = $.trim($("#descripcion_domicilio").val());
    telefono = $.trim($("#telefono").val());
    num_contrato = $.trim($("#num_contrato").val());
    fecha_inicio = $.trim($("#fecha_inicio").val());
    fecha_final = $.trim($("#fecha_final").val());
    cuadrilla = $.trim($("#cuadrilla").val());
    estatus = $.trim($("#estatus").val());
    observaciones = $.trim($("#observaciones").val());
    encargado_cuadrilla = $.trim($("#encargado_cuadrilla").val());
    otra_descripcion = $.trim($("#otra_descripcion").val());
    $.ajax({
      url: "../controlador/reportes.php",
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "json",
      data: {
        id: id,
        folio: folio,
        nombre: nombre,
        apellido: apellido,
        direccion: direccion,
        descripcion_domicilio: descripcion_domicilio,
        telefono: telefono,
        num_contrato: num_contrato,
        fecha_inicio: fecha_inicio,
        fecha_final: fecha_final,
        cuadrilla: cuadrilla,
        estatus: estatus,
        observaciones: observaciones,
        encargado_cuadrilla: encargado_cuadrilla,
        otra_descripcion: otra_descripcion,
        opcion: opcion,
      },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        tablaReportes.ajax.reload(null, false);
      },
    });
    $("#modalCRUD").modal("hide");
  });
  //para limpiar los campos antes de dar de Alta una Persona
  $("#btnNuevo").click(function () {
    opcion = 1; //alta
    id = null;
    $("#formReportes").trigger("reset");
    $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#17a2b8");
    $(".modal-header").css("color", "white");
    $(".modal-title").text("Alta Reportes");
    $("#modalCRUD").modal("show");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".btnPrint", function (e) {
    window.open(
      "./../Reports/orden.php?id=" +
        Number(
          e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(
            ".sorting_1"
          ).textContent
        ),
      "_black"
    );
  });

  //Editar
  $(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function () {
    opcion = 2; //editar
    fila = $(this).closest("tr");
    id = parseInt(fila.find("td:eq(0)").text()); //capturo el ID
    folio = fila.find("td:eq(1)").text();
    nombre = fila.find("td:eq(2)").text();
    apellido = fila.find("td:eq(3)").text();
    direccion = fila.find("td:eq(4)").text();
    descripcion_domicilio = fila.find("td:eq(5)").text();
    telefono = fila.find("td:eq(6)").text();
    num_contrato = fila.find("td:eq(7)").text();
    fecha_inicio = fila.find("td:eq(8)").text();
    fecha_final = fila.find("td:eq(9)").text();
    cuadrilla = fila.find("td:eq(10)").text();
    estatus = fila.find("td:eq(11)").text();
    observaciones = fila.find("td:eq(12)").text();
    encargado_cuadrilla = fila.find("td:eq(13)").text();
    otra_descripcion = fila.find("td:eq(14)").text();
    $("#folio").val(folio);
    $("#nombre").val(nombre);
    $("#apellido").val(apellido);
    $("#direccion").val(direccion);
    $("#descripcion_domicilio").val(descripcion_domicilio);
    $("#telefono").val(telefono);
    $("#num_contrato").val(num_contrato);
    $("#fecha_inicio").val(fecha_inicio);
    $("#fecha_final").val(fecha_final);
    $("#cuadrilla option:contains(" + cuadrilla + ")").attr("selected", "");
    $("#estatus option:contains(" + estatus + ")").attr("selected", "");
    $("#observaciones").val(observaciones);
    $("#encargado_cuadrilla").val(encargado_cuadrilla);
    $("#otra_descripcion").val(otra_descripcion);
    $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#007bff");
    $(".modal-header").css("color", "white");
    $(".modal-title").text("Editar Reporte");
    $("#modalCRUD").modal("show");
  });

  //Borrar
  $(document).on("click", ".btnBorrar", function () {
    fila = $(this);
    id = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text());
    opcion = 3; //eliminar
    var respuesta = confirm("¿Está seguro de borrar el registro " + id + "?");
    if (respuesta) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "../controlador/reportes.php",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { opcion: opcion, id: id },
        success: function () {
          tablaReportes.row(fila.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
        },
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Dejo una foto de mi crud

[image: CRUD]

Esto me muestra en mi consola

[image: crud]

Error en la ultima actualización

[image: Error]

[image: error2]

Comment: @Triby entonces cambio esas opciones?

Comment: @Triby entonces sugiere cambiar esos valores. Espero su repuesta, en verdad muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: @Triby ya actualicé el código y subí los cambios. Para que pueda visualizar.

Comment: @Triby me manda error en el fragmento de código de separar horas, minutos y segundos.

Comment: @Triby sigo sin poder solucionar el problema, ya intenté hacer cambios de lo que posiblemente esté mal, pero no logro poder correr el sistema, ya subí los cambios, en cuanto puedas por favor revisa el código que subí actualizado.

Comment: ¿De dónde salió `cellData[8]`? Intenta cambiar `if (calcDays(cellData[8]) >= 5)` por `if (calcDays(cellData) >= 5)`, es decir, quitando los corchetes y el 8.

Comment: @Triby ya funciono, ahora los nuevos registros no aparecen en rojo, pero tengo una duda, si quisiera que los ya tiene fecha finalizada, se puede poner de color verde y los que no tiene aún fecha finalizada, se quede en rojo?

Comment: En `columnDefs` agrega el objeto para la columna correspondiente: target con el número de columna y createdCell con la función para pintar. Si ya te funcionó esto, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada, para que otros usuarios con problemas similares sepan que les puede servir.

Comment: @Triby veo que eres bueno, algúna red social donde te pueda contactar para futuras ayudas, claro siempre y cuando estés disponible y porsupuesto que podria pagarte por tus ayudas y asesorias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Importante:** El tipo de dato en la columna 8 no es numérico, entonces, la comparación `rowData[8] >= 5` difícilmente funcionará como esperas. Tratándose de fechas, debes recurrir al objeto [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Al inicio de tu script crea el objeto para la fecha actual, para que no tengas que hacerlo en cada comparación y también crea una función que reciba la fecha a comparar y devuelva los días de diferencia con la actual:

```js
// Fecha actual en milisegundos
const today = Date.now();
function calcDays(dateStr) {
    // Separar fecha y hora
    let [dt, tm] = dateStr.split(' ');
    // Separar año, mes y día
    let [Y, M, D] = dt.split('-');
    // Separar horas, minutos y segundos
    let [h, m, s] = tm.split(':');
    
    // Crear objeto de fecha, se tienen que enviar todos los parámetros separados
    let dateObj = new Date(Y, M - 1, D, h, m, s);
    // Obtener diferencia entre ambas fechas, dividido entre 1000 para que sean segundos
    let timeDiff = parseInt((today - dateObj.getTime()) / 1000);
    // Dividir diferencia entre 86400 que son los segundos por día (60*60*24)
    let days = parseInt(timeDiff / 86400);
    // Fechas anteriores dan números positivos
    return days;
}

// Esto es solo para probar, no lo incluyas en tu proyecto
console.log(calcDays('2022-08-21 14:46:45')); // Negativo, es fecha futura
console.log(calcDays('2022-07-08 07:10:05')); // Positivo, es fecha anterior
```

Después de definir el origen de datos de cada celda, agrega otra propiedad [columnDefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) para especificar el comportamiento de la celda deseada:

**Edición:** De acuerdo a lo que resulta de `console.log(cellData, rowData[8], calcDays(rowData[8]));`, hay que usar la variable `cellData` para obtener la cantidad de días.

```
columns: [
  { data: "id" },
  { data: "folio" },
  { data: "nombre" },
  { data: "apellido" },
  { data: "direccion" },
  { data: "descripcion_domicilio" },
  { data: "telefono" },
  { data: "num_contrato" },
  { data: "fecha_inicio" },
  { data: "fecha_final" },
  {
    data: "cuadrilla",
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
      switch (data) {
        case "1":
          data =
            '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Operación ciudad</span>';
          break;
        case "2":
          data =
            '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Operación megasistema</span>';
          break;
        case "3":
          data =
            '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Drenajes</span>';
          break;
        case "4":
          data =
            '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Tomas tapadas</span>';
          break;
        case "5":
          data =
            '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">Cloración</span>';
          break;
        case "6":
          data = '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">Bacheo</span>';
          break;
        case "7":
          data =
            '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">Contratos</span>';
          break;
        case "8":
          data = '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">Otros</span>';
          break;
        default:
          data = "";
      }
      return data;
    },
  },
  {
    data: "estatus",
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
      switch (data) {
        case "1":
          data = '<span class="badge badge-warning">Inicio</span>';
          break;
        case "2":
          data = '<span class="badge badge-warning">Pendiente</span>';
          break;
        case "3":
          data = '<span class="badge badge-success">Terminado</span>';
          break;
        case "4":
          data = '<span class="badge badge-danger">Cancelado</span>';
          break;
        default:
          data = "";
      }
      return data;
    },
  },
  { data: "observaciones" },
  { data: "encargado_cuadrilla" },
  { data: "otra_descripcion" },
  {
    defaultContent: `<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnPrint'><i class='material-icons'>print</i></button><button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons'>delete</i></button></div></div>`,
  },
], // Aquí termina columns
columnDefs: [
    {
        // Aplicar solo a celda 8
        targets: 8,
        // Ejecutar cuando se crea la celda
        createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            // Ejecuta la función para calcular diferencia
            if(calcDays(cellData) >= 5) {
                $(td).css('background-color', '#E60026');
            }
        }
    }
],
```

Dejo esto después de la edición solo para que quede claro cómo usar los selectores en jQuery.

No estás usando un selector adecuado, necesitas seleccionar por índice con el método [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$(row).find('td').eq(8).css("background-color","#E60026");
```

Breve explicación:

- `$(row)`: Selecciona la fila
- `.find('td')`: Obtiene todas las celdas
- `.eq(8)`: Selecciona la celda 9, porque el índice comienza en cero

Comment: Gracias, pero aún no me aparece coloreado, creo que ha de ser porque tengo que realizar un nuevo registro.

Comment: Hola, subí otra captura de mi código, no sé por qué no me los está pintando de color @Triby

Comment: ya lo estoy revisando.

Comment: Tengo un una duda @Triby en columnDefs: [ es dos puntos o es columnDefs = [

Comment: Subí una imagen de como quedo con las instrucciones que me indicaste.

Comment: Hola, Acabo de agregar todo el código. En verdad muchas gracias por tu ayuda y paciencia.

Comment: agregué una imagen de lo que me muestra.

Comment: @AndrésdeJesús, acabo de actualizar la respuesta cambiando la función que calcula los días, probablemente ahí es donde obtienes el error.

Comment: Windows 10, Mozilla Developer y Chrome, subi una nueva imagen de donde apunta el error

Comment: @AndrésdeJesús, dos cosas: 1. Edita la pregunta para agregar tu código actual, creo que no estás enviando el parámetro correcto. 2. Elimina comentarios en esta respuesta.

Comment: ya realicé lo que me pediste, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: ya corregí la pregunta, la cambia a Error en pintar Celda en Datatable php